# Criterion for disconnectedness of affine algebraic set.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to prove that, if $V$ is an affine algebraic set, then $V$ is connected in the Zariski topology iff $k[V]$ is not the direct sum of two ideals. Note that $k$ is algebraically closed here.

So, first I started by assuming that $k[V]=I_1\oplus I_2$. Then, using the Chinese Remainder Theorem and basic properties of the correspondence between ideals and algebraic sets, I was able to write $V=\mathcal Z(I_1)\sqcup\mathcal Z(I_2)$, but of course, to show that the set is not connected, I need to write $V$ as a disjoint union of OPEN sets, not closed sets. I tried showing that they were open by doing some tricks with their complements (which are NOT necessarily each other, since $V$ may not be the whole space).

How do I finish this argument? Am I on the right track?

Comment: It seems like the confusion is coming from outside algebraic geometry. You don't want to write $V$ as a disjoint union of two sets open in $\mathbb{A}^n$. Indeed, this would imply that $V$ were open in $\mathbb{A}^n$ and that's probably not true. Everything is in the subspace topology!

Comment: Oh, I guess I only have to prove they're open in $V$, which is easy, since they're complements of each other?

Comment: Hmm, I'm having trouble finding a disconnected $V$ where $k[V]$ is not the direct sum of two ideals when $k$ is not algebraically closed...do you know any?

Comment: Yes, I think you've done all the hard work already. I'd have to think about this second question -- for schemes even the fact that you're working over a field seems irrelevant but I want to think about whether that passes down to your setting.

Comment: Yeah, I'm learning Algebraic Geometry through Dummit and Foote, so all the knowledge I have comes from the first 2 sections of Chapter 15 of that book.

Comment: Hmm, I've reduced it to finding a case where $I(V_1)+I(V_2)\subsetneq I(V_1\cap V_2)$, since then the coordinate ring won't be the sum of the ideals. These ideals will always intersect trivially, since $I(V)=0$ in the coordinate ring.